# Magento 2: How to override UI component XML grid?

Tags: magento2, overrides, uicomponent

I need to override **sales_order_grid.xml** from **ui_component** of **Magento_Sales**.

I want to remove some part of it but I don't know how to override it, I know how to override phtml from the custom module but for **ui_component** I have no idea.

**[EDIT]**

I will have multiple admin account, I don't want them to have access to some options and also I don't want them to see useless columns. The less thing they have to do the better it is.

**[EDIT2]**

Ok, i find that I can make in custom module the **sales_order_grid.xml** file under **view/adminhtml/ui_component/**. So this is the file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Purchase Date</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY, H:MM:SS A</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

As you can see, I try to set visible to false for **created_at** column.

Result : The column is still here, but not the filter panel like I show here :

[image]

Also, when I inspect element, and I set **Display: none** to the table, the block is here.

Comment: What do you mean you want to overwrite parts? you know you can choose which columns show via the UI

Comment: I know, but I want to remove some part, i know it's useless but i will have multiple admin account, I don't want them to have access to some option and also I don't want them to see useless columns. The less thing they have to do the better it is.

Comment: You can create bookmarks and save profiles in it. Uncheck the columns you don't want and save it.

Comment: I know, but that's not what i want, I will create multiple admin users, and I want them to already have the correct view, I don't want them have to change columns and save bookmark.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue while overriding sales_order_grid.xml from ui_component for me the below solution worked:

Add the `<sequence>` tag as shown in the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CT_OrderCancel" setup_version="1.0.1" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Thanks.